# How to fetch and display foreign key value on blade correctly in a laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to build a small crud app using laravel.

In my DB I have two tables for companies and employees.

company id is a foreign key value for the employee table.

Users can select a company from a dropdown when creating a new employee.

My question is when I try to display my user details in a table, how can I display the company name as it currently stores the company id in my employee table?

Following is my index function in EmployeeController

```
public function index()
    {
        $data = Employee::latest()->paginate(10);

        return view('employees.index', compact('data'))->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 10);
    }
```

and this is my table on index blade.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Phone </th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                @if(count($data) > 0)
    
                    @foreach($data as $row)
    
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $row->first_name }} {{ $row->last_name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $row->email }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $row->phone }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="{{ route('employees.show', $row->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">View</a>
                                <a href="{{ route('employees.edit', $row->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Edit</a>
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-target="#delUser">Delete</a>
                                <!-- Delete company Modal -->
                                <div class="modal fade" id="delUser" role="dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    
                                    <!-- Modal content-->
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <p>Do you sure want to delete this company? This operation cannot be reverted!</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <form  action="{{ route('employees.destroy',$row->id) }}" method="POST">
                                                @csrf
                                                @method('DELETE')
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                @else
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5" class="text-center">No Data Found</td>
                    </tr>
                @endif
            </table>
```

How can I display user's company name, not the ID....

My companies table

[image]

My employees table

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the relation in your `Employee` model https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

```
    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }
```

Next, on controller, you have to eager load as:

```
$data = Employee::with('company')->latest()->paginate(10);
```

And, on view, you could get the employee name as:

```
$row->company->name
```

You could find, more about eager loading on https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading